# Converting json to geojson

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm quite new to R and I was trying to make an interactive map showing coronavirus cases.

I was planning to use leaflet for R to create the map and using this source (https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json) for the data.
However, leaflet requires the data to be in .geojson.
How do I convert the data to the .geojson format?

Comment: You need coordinates and your data source have no one. This will not work

Comment: According to documentation, the leaflet function in the leaflet package accepts the following data: currently supported objects are matrices, data frames, spatial objects from the sp package (SpatialPoints, SpatialPointsDataFrame, Polygon, Polygons, SpatialPolygons, SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, Line, Lines, SpatialLines, and SpatialLinesDataFrame), and spatial data frames from the sf package.

Comment: @FalkeDesign oh ok; the data is sorted by countries, can I add the coordinates with the information about the countries?

Comment: You need to provide coordinates for all of the countries. One way might be to see this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/71921/70363. From there, you would need to join/merge coordinates into your regular json data.